# pandas.DataFrame.from_dict faster alternative

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dictionary of equally sized numpy arrays, that I want to get into a DataFrame, where each on of the values in the numpy arrays becomes a column. For example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as np

my_dict = {
    "key_1": np.arange((50_000)),
    "key_2": np.arange((50_000)),
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient="index")

#        0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      10     ...  49989  49990  49991  49992  49993  49994  49995  49996  49997  49998  49999
# key_1      0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10  ...  49989  49990  49991  49992  49993  49994  49995  49996  49997  49998  49999
# key_2      0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10  ...  49989  49990  49991  49992  49993  49994  49995  49996  49997  49998  49999

# [2 rows x 50000 columns]
```

If you run this, you'll see the `my_dict` creation is very quick, but the `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict` is noticeably slow.

I'm looking for a way of getting something equivalent that has better performance.

Just to give more context, just incase this step can maybe be skipped completely, the final intent is to get that `pandas.DataFrame` reindexed with a arbitrarily list of key names:

```py
occurrences = ["key_1", "key_1", "key_2", "key_1", "key_2"]
df = df.reindex(occurrences)

#        0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      10     ...  49989  49990  49991  49992  49993  49994  49995  49996  49997  49998  49999
# key_1      0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10  ...  49989  49990  49991  49992  49993  49994  49995  49996  49997  49998  49999
# key_1      0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10  ...  49989  49990  49991  49992  49993  49994  49995  49996  49997  49998  49999
# key_2      0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10  ...  49989  49990  49991  49992  49993  49994  49995  49996  49997  49998  49999
# key_1      0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10  ...  49989  49990  49991  49992  49993  49994  49995  49996  49997  49998  49999
# key_2      0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10  ...  49989  49990  49991  49992  49993  49994  49995  49996  49997  49998  49999

# [5 rows x 50000 columns]
```

Maybe a faster way just going directly from `occurrences` and `my_dict`.

EDIT: Sorry, I should have mentioned, the `np.arange((50_000))` is just an example to make a large array. I can assert the data looks like that, it's just arbitrary values, but all of the same length. Also, I'm trying to avoid python loops (such as comprehensions) and use `pandas` or `numpy` as the size of these items can get very large.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
>>> occurrences = ["key_1", "key_2", "key_3", "key_4", "key_5"]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dict.fromkeys(occurrences, range(50_000))).T
```

If indeed there are duplicate indices:

```
>>> occurrences = ['key_1', 'key_1', 'key_2', 'key_1', 'key_2']
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
             data=np.repeat([np.arange(50_000)], repeats=len(occurrences), axis=0), 
             index=occurrences
         )
```

In case you already have a predefined `dict`. For example, `my_dict`, use `transpose`:

```
>>> my_dict = {
    "key_1": np.arange((50_000)),
    "key_2": np.arange((50_000)),
}
>>> %timeit pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient="index")
3.21 s ± 62.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

>>> %timeit pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict).T
551 µs ± 75 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks @Cyttorak. Unfortunately, the `np.arange(50_000)` was just to make example data, I cant assert the data will look like that. It's as good as random.

Comment: oh my.... that's a lot faster... How did you think to try that?

Comment: According to [source of from_dict](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.4/pandas/core/frame.py#L1296-L1373), `orient=index` involves a little preprocessing, whereas `orient=columns`, i.e. the default behavior is a normal dataframe constructor. And `.T` is just a property, which has almost no performance hit.

Comment: `df.T` calls `df.transpose` but still fast